# Palíndromo em C++

Tags: c++, string

O código abaixo funciona, recebe o que foi digitado e armazena o mesmo, só que não faz a lógica para mostrar se é palíndromo ou não e não apresenta na tela o resultado para o usuário.

Por favor, onde errei e como consertar?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

    string Texto = "";
    bool palindrono = true;
    int posicaoReversa = 0;

        cout << "Digite a palavra : " ;
        cin >> Texto;

    for (int i = Texto.length() -1; i > 0; i--)
    {

        posicaoReversa = Texto.length() - i - 1;

        if (Texto.substr(i, 1) != Texto.substr(posicaoReversa, 1))
        {
            palindrono = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Recebe e armazena o valor, mas não mostra o resultado ao usuário]

Comment: Fiz um teste e parece estar ok. Só não apresenta para o usuário? Você não está mandando apresentar. Você sabe que precisaria apresentar o resultando no final, provavelmente com `cout`? O programa não vai apresentar sozinho se você não mandar. Você não sabe como fazer isto?

Comment: bigown sei que devo apresentar com o cout, mas não estou sabendo em que trcho do código colocar este ultimo cout.

Comment: Fiz algumas melhorias que talvez possam te ajudar a melhorar seu código. Espero que te ajude. Veja funcionando no [ideoone](http://ideone.com/Yg1LiL).

Comment: Será legal quando você melhorar para ignorar acentos, espaço e pontuação, aí fica completamente funcional :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Só faltava colocar a apresentação do resultado, só acrescentei uma linha no final da verificação dos caracteres. Comentei algumas melhorias que você pode fazer no seu código e as fiz no [exemplo mostrado no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Yg1LiL), considere especialmente cortar pela metade o tempo do algoritmo evitando comparar o que já foi comparado:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    string Texto = ""; //foi sempre usado camelcase, esta variável também deveria ser
    bool palindrono = true; //o nome da variável deveria ser palindromo
    int posicaoReversa = 0; //variável desnecessária
    cout << "Digite a palavra : ";
    cin >> Texto;
    //seria melhor pegar o tamanho do texto for do loop por questões de performance
    //também seria melhor comparar só até a metade, veja no ideone o exemplo modificado
    for (int i = Texto.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        posicaoReversa = Texto.length() - i - 1; //não precisava colocar na variável
        //poderia usar o operador [] que já pega uma posição da string
        if (Texto.substr(i, 1) != Texto.substr(posicaoReversa, 1)) {
            palindrono = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //terminou todo o processamento necessário, chegará aqui em duas situações:
    //1. ocorreu o break saindo do for e mandando para cá (não é palindromo)
    //2. terminou o loop do for e não tem mais o que repetir (é palindromo)
    cout << endl << (palindrono ? "É palindromo" : "Não é palindromo");
}
```

Fiz algumas otimizações e melhorias no estilo do código:

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gPr0i2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fxhmmpgx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Palindrome.cpp).

Quando você compara `arara`, por exemplo, você só precisa comparar a última com a primeira e a penúltima com a segunda. Originalmente executava mais três comparações desnecessárias: comparava a do meio com ela mesma, a segunda com a penúltima (que você já tinha comparado) e a primeira com a última (também já tinha comparado). O código não estava errado, apenas poderia ser melhorado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Eu estava colocando errado mesmo.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Além de aceitar como certa uma resposta, você já tem reputação para poder votar em todas as respostas que te ajudaram. E votar nas perguntas e respostas de outras pessoas também. Pode votar em tudo. Veja o [tour].

Comment: você esta certo, Eu ainda me perco muito neste site, sempre achei que aceitar como certa era o mesmo que votar, preciso aprender mais sobre este site.

Comment: Aceitar você só pode uma resposta em perguntas que você fez. Votar você pode em qualquer postagem, pergunta, resposta, de quem for, só não pode votar nas suas, claro :) Pelo menos onde você está envolvido veja onde você deixou de votar e acha que merece o voto.