# Como identificar se uma string é um palíndromo?

Tags: python, string, algoritmo

Um palíndromo é uma palavra ou frase que tenha a propriedade de poder ser lida tanto da direita para a esquerda como da esquerda para a direita. Por exemplo, as strings `"aaaaa"`, `"1221"`, `"bbaabb"` são palíndromos, entretanto a string `"chef"` não é um palíndromo.

Para os casos onde é dada uma frase, espaços e as diferenças entre maiúsculas e minúsculas são ignorados. Por exemplo: a frase `"A base do teto desaba"` é considerada um palíndromo. Ao lê-la da direita para a esquerda, você obterá: `"abased otet od esab A"`. Perceba que, com exceção do espaço, a sequência de caracteres é a mesma da frase original.

Como escrever um programa que indique se uma string dada é um palíndromo ou não, utilizando conhecimento de strings?

Comment: Ola Guilherme, o que vc ja tentou fazer? Onde esta ocorrendo suas dificuldades? Assim fica melhor para a comunidade ajudar vc.

Comment: Faça uma copia da string e jogue em uma variável, nele aplique um reverse ou similar e faça a comparação da original com a cópia. É uma ideia inicial.

Comment: Relacionados: [Inversão de string palíndromo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112324/91), [Palíndromo em C++](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35451/91) e [Preciso de diferentes formas de reorganizar caracteres dentro de uma string, como faço isso?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85688/91)

Comment: Ainda não tentei nenhum código. Apenas penso que o jeito correto seria começar com raw_input() para que o usuário forneça uma string a ler lida, e que utilizando str[::-1] eu possa fazer uma comparação. Para contornar os espaços, penso em retirá-los da string inicial para que a comparação funcione. O que acham?

Comment: Se for para verificar uma unica palavra na string, esta rotina: `if palavra == palavra[::-1]:` poderia funcionar, caso contrario vc teria que remover as palavras, mais para verificar a frase toda sugiro da uma olhada nas outras perguntas sobre o assunto.

Comment: Obrigado! Irei tentar.

Comment: Ze de Lima, Rua Laura mil e dez.

Comment: Consegui escrever um programa que atende ao propósito. Mas existe uma condição: A primeira entrada deve ser um número inteiro, que corresponde ao número de strings que serão testadas. Se eu fornecer o número 3, devo fornecer 3 strings e, após escrever a última, o programa deve fazer o julgamento para cada string. Irei editar a pergunta e mostrar como fiz até agora. Como proceder?

Comment: @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza Se você já conseguiu fazer a parte do palíndromo, sua próxima dúvida já é algo mais geral. Acho que é melhor deixar essa pergunta como está, publicar a sua solução como resposta e abrir outra (que não menciona o palíndromo, pois não precisa)

Comment: Entendido. Obrigado!

Comment: Pelo que me lembre poderia separar todos os caracteres e jogar invertido em um  vetor e depois comparar. (Para separar tem que fazer o procedimento em ASCI)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
string = raw_input()
stringSemEspacos = string.replace(' ', '')
stringTodaMinuscula = stringSemEspacos.lower()
stringInvertida = stringTodaMinuscula[::-1]
if stringInvertida == stringTodaMinuscula:
    print "SIM"
else:
    print "NAO"
```

Após a string ser fornecida pelo usuário, os espaços são substituídos por uma nulidade utilizando `replace()` (caso a string seja uma frase), atribuindo essa nova string a uma outra variável `stringSemEspacos`. Caso a string possua letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, a função `lower()` converte `stringSemEspacos` em `stringTodaMinuscula`, que possui apenas letras minúsculas. Posteriormente, a string é invertida (`stringTodaMinuscula[::-1]`), e comparada com `stringSemEspaços`. A comparação testa se `stringSemEspaços` e `stringInvertida` (string com letras invertidas) são iguais. Sendo iguais, a string inicial fornecida confere um palíndromo.

Comment: Qual foi a edição?

Comment: Ele adicionou um [titulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/120438/revisions) ao código, mais seria interessante vc explicar como resolveu e como o código funciona, assim vc ajuda outras pessoas.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado.

Comment: O seu código poderia ter sido diminuido para apenas 6 linhas se você fizesse todas as passagens de uma vez na string

Comment: @ViniciusMesel, estavas a pensar:  `a=raw_input().replace(' ', '').lower(); print a==a[::-1]`   ?(gosto: Parece Perl  ☺ )

Comment: @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza exatamente assim que eu faria!

Answer (score 4):

Complementando as outras respostas...

A maioria acabou usando o *slice* `[::-1]`, que gera uma outra string com os caracteres na ordem inversa.

Isso de fato funciona, mas se a ideia é **somente verificar** se a string é igual à sua inversa, não precisa criar outra string: basta iterar pelos caracteres da mesma, verificando se o primeiro é igual ao último, depois se o segundo é igual ao penúltimo, e assim por diante. O detalhe é que assim só precisamos iterar até a metade da string (além de não precisar criar outra):

```
def palindromo(string):
    size = len(string)
    if size == 0:
        # Se a string é vazia, ela é ou não é palíndromo? Estou considerando que não
        return False
    for i in range(0, size // 2):
        if string[i] != string[size - i - 1]: # encontrei diferença, nem precisa continuar
            return False
    return True
```

<sup>*Só fiquei em dúvida quanto ao caso da string ser vazia (pois pode-se debater se ela é ou não palíndromo), mas enfim, estou considerando que não.*</sup>

Outra forma de fazer a mesma coisa, usando [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
def palindromo(string):
    size = len(string)
    if size == 0:
        # Se a string é vazia, ela é ou não é palíndromo? Estou considerando que não
        return False
    return all(string[i] == string[size - i - 1] for i in range(0, size // 2))
```

---

> *Para os casos onde é dada uma frase, espaços e as diferenças entre maiúsculas e minúsculas são ignorados.*

Nesse caso, as outras respostas sugerem diferentes métodos para remover os caracteres que não são letras (como espaços, pontuações, etc), e até mesmo o uso de [normalização Unicode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052) para tratar os acentos, etc. Creio que o uso de tais métodos varia conforme a necessidade e os casos que você quer ou não considerar, e sobre este ponto específico (remover caracteres que não serão considerados na verificação) não há muito mais a acrescentar.

Mas tem outros pontos que acho que valem algumas considerações:

---

#### Ignorar diferença entre maiúsculas e minúsculas

Para comparações *case insensitive*, a documentação menciona o uso do [método `casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), que segundo a descrição, é "mais agressivo" que `lower` (que foi o método usado nas outras respostas): "*Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string*".

Um exemplo citado é do caractere alemão `ß`, que quando convertido para maiúscula se torna "SS" ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340161/112052)), e por isso em uma comparação *case insensitive* seria considerado equivalente a "ss".

Neste caso, a função acima teria que usar `casefold` no início:

```
def palindromo(string):
    string = string.casefold()
    # restante do código igual...
```

Claro que assim estamos gerando uma nova string (já que `casefold` retorna outra string), mas pelo menos é uma só, pois o restante do algoritmo continua iterando até a metade da mesma. Agora a string `'ßSS'` é considerada palíndromo (mas se usássemos `lower` no lugar de `casefold`, ou se usássemos o primeiro código acima, não seria palíndromo).

Ou seja, cabe a você decidir qual método usar, já que isso depende do critério a ser considerado (e também se as strings que você vai testar terão caracteres que apresentem esta diferença).

---

#### Unicode e Grapheme clusters

Se quiser saber em detalhes o que é um *Grapheme cluster*, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052), mas basicamente, podem existir grupos de code points que juntos significam uma coisa só (como os [*emojis* de famílias](https://emojipedia.org/families/), além de caracteres usados em outros idiomas).

Um exemplo é esta string: `"नुच्छे"`. Não parece, mas ela tem 6 code points (e para saber o que é um code point, visite os links já indicados no parágrafo anterior):

```
s = "नुच्छे"
print(len(s)) # 6
from unicodedata import name, normalize
for c in normalize('NFC', s):
    print(f'{ord(c):06X}\t', c, name(c, ''))
```

Saída:

```
6
000928   न DEVANAGARI LETTER NA
000941   ु DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN U
00091A   च DEVANAGARI LETTER CA
00094D   ् DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA
00091B   छ DEVANAGARI LETTER CHA
000947   े DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN E
```

Só que o primeiro e segundo code points "se juntam" em um *grapheme cluster* (passam a ser "uma coisa só"), que no caso é o caractere `नु`. O mesmo acontece com os demais: cada 2 code points se juntam para formar um único caractere. E neste caso, não adianta usar normalização Unicode (como foi usado no exemplo acima), que eles continuarão separados.

Então se eu tiver uma string como `"नुच्छेच्नु"` (o primeiro e último são o mesmo *grapheme cluster*, assim como o segundo e o penúltimo), a função `palindromo` não funciona mais, pois ao acessar os caracteres de uma string, estamos na verdade acessando os code points individualmente. E nesse caso também não adianta usar `[::-1]`, pois aí você estará invertendo a ordem dos code points, gerando uma string inválida (já que a ordem dos code points é importante em um *grapheme cluster*).

O mesmo vale para os *emojis* de família, que na verdade são uma junção de vários code points. Ex:

```
s = ''.join(map(chr, [0x1F468, 0x200d, 0x1F469, 0x200d, 0x1F467, 0x200d, 0x1F467]))
print(s)
```

Se o seu terminal/IDE tiver suporte a *emojis*, será mostrado algo como:

[image]

Claro que a imagem varia conforme o sistema (e caso não seja suportado, pode ser mostrado o homem, a mulher e as crianças um do lado do outro, por exemplo).

O que importa é que esse é um *grapheme cluster*: um grupo de vários code points que são considerados uma coisa só. E nenhum dos métodos apresentados até agora considera que isso é um palíndromo (seria como uma string contendo um único "caractere", já que ao invertê-lo, o resultado deveria ser o mesmo *emoji*).

---

Nesse caso não há muita alternativa a não ser tratar os *grapheme clusters* um a um. Você pode tanto ler o [documento do Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) e implementar as regras, ou então usar algo pronto.

Um exemplo que encontrei é o [módulo `grapheme`](https://pypi.org/project/grapheme/). Com ele podemos quebrar a string em *grapheme clusters* e usar o mesmo algoritmo acima (compara o primeiro com o último, o segundo com o penúltimo, etc):

```
# Atenção: módulo não-nativo - Instale em https://pypi.org/project/grapheme/
from grapheme import graphemes

def palindromo(string):
    grapheme_clusters = list(graphemes(string.casefold()))
    size = len(grapheme_clusters)
    if size == 0:
        # Se a string é vazia, ela é ou não é palíndromo? Estou considerando que não
        return False
    for i in range(0, size // 2):
        if grapheme_clusters[i] != grapheme_clusters[size - i - 1]: # encontrei diferença, nem precisa continuar
            return False
    return True

s = "नुच्छेच्नु"
print(palindromo(s)) # True

# funciona também para o emoji de família
s = ''.join(map(chr, [0x1F468, 0x200d, 0x1F469, 0x200d, 0x1F467, 0x200d, 0x1F467]))
print(palindromo(s)) # True

# continua funcionando para strings "normais"
for s in ['aba', 'a', '', 'ab', 'aa', 'abc', 'abcdedcba', 'aabbaa', 'ßSS']:
    print(s, palindromo(s))
```

Ou, usando `all`:

```
def palindromo(string):
    grapheme_clusters = list(graphemes(string.casefold()))
    size = len(grapheme_clusters)
    if size == 0:
        # Se a string é vazia, ela é ou não é palíndromo? Estou considerando que não
        return False
    return all(grapheme_clusters[i] == grapheme_clusters[size - i - 1] for i in range(0, size // 2))
```

Claro que faltou aplicar a remoção dos caracteres indesejados (espaços, pontuação, etc), mas como já dito, basta ver as outras respostas e escolher o que melhor atende sua necessidade (já que a remoção é ortogonal ao tratamento dos *grapheme clusters*).

Answer (score 2):

Para decidir de uma frase é palíndromo ou não, ignorando espaços em branco, pontos e vírgulas.

```
frase = raw_input('Informe uma frase').split(" ")  # retira espaço em branco
aux = ""

for i in range(0, len(frase)):
    aux += frase[i]

frase = aux.split(".") #retira os pontos
aux = ""

for i in range(0, len(frase)): #retira os pontos
    aux += frase[i]

frase = aux.split(",") #retira as vírgulas
aux = ""

for i in range(0, len(frase)): #retira as vírgulas
    aux += frase[i]

if aux.lower() == aux.lower()[::-1]: #verifica usando minúsculo e invertido
    print 'É palíndromo'
else:
    print 'Não é palíndromo'
```

Espero que tenha ajudado...;-)

Answer (score 2):

Aqui está uma forma simplificada que encontrei para resolver a questão.

Aí vai o código..

```
palavra_1 = str(input('Qual palavra deseja verificar se é um palídromo? '))
palavra_2 = palavra_1.lower().strip().replace(' ', '')
if palavra_2 == palavra_2[::-1]:
    print(palavra_1)
    print('É um palídromo')
else:
   print('Não é um palídromo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas para verifica se uma palavra é palíndromo é:

```
palavra = input('Digite uma palavra: ').lower().strip().replace(' ', '')
if palavra == palavra[::-1]:
    print('É palíndromo')
else:
    print('Não é palíndromo')
```

Agora se preferir uma função para verifica se uma palavra é palíndromo podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def palindromo(pala):
    if pala == pala[::-1]:
        return True
    return False


palavra = input('Digite uma palavra: ').lower().strip().replace(' ', '')

print(palindromo(palavra))
```

Observe também que a saída deste segundo código é apenas uma afirmação - **True ou False** .

Observe que quando executamos **ambos** os códigos recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite uma palavra:` . Neste momento devemos digitar a palavra desejada e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, o bloco `if` de ambos os códigos irá verificar se **palavra** é igual ao **reverso da palavra**. Caso positivo, a resposta será positiva. Caso negativo, a resposta será negativa.

**Observação:** O reverso de uma palavra é a escrita da palavra em sentido oposto.

Answer (score -1):

## Te desafio a encontrar um palíndromo ou não palíndromo não detectável por este algorítimo!

Precisamos normalizar o texto antes de comparar com seu inverso, caso contrário, um acento pode gerar um falso negativo.
Para normalizar, vamos utilizar o normalize('NFKD', s), que converte para unistr e aplica a decomposição de compatibilidade, ou seja, substitui todos os caracteres de compatibilidade por seus equivalentes (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).
Convertemos para 'ASCII', assim os caracteres acentuados vão ser trocados por seus equivalentes sem acento e ignorando os que não possuem equivalencia.
Voltamos o texto para Unicode, convertemos para minusculas e, por ultimo, utilizamos regex para deixar apenas de a-z, A-Z e 0-9 (É possível um palindromo com números)

```
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

def slugfy(s):
    """
    Remove caracteres e acentos ignoráveis
    """
    return re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+','', normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ASCII','ignore').decode('ASCII')).lower()

def is_palindrome(s):
    """
    Verifica se é igual a ao termo invertido ignorando espaços
    e termos fora do range A-z0-9
    """
    s = re.sub('\s+','',s) # remove whitespaces
    return bool(s and s == s[::-1] or slugfy(s) and slugfy(s) == slugfy(s)[::-1])

text = is_palindrome(
    input('Digite um palindromo: ')
)

if text:
    print('Habemos um palindromo!!!')
else:
    print('Tentei ler de traz pra frente e não deu certo amigão!')
```

Palindromos mais conhecidos pra testar:

```
palindromos = [
    "Roma me tem amor.",
    "Socorram-me, subi no ônibus em Marrocos!",
    "A mala nada na lama. ",
    "A grama é amarga. ",
    "A Rita, sobre vovô, verbos atira.",
    "Olé! Maracujá, caju, caramelo!",
    "Rir, o breve verbo rir.",
    "Anotaram a data da maratona.",
    "A mãe te ama.",
    "Oto come mocotó.",
    "A torre da derrota.",
    "Ótimo, só eu, que os omito.",
    "O galo ama o lago.",
    "O lobo ama o bolo.",
    "Mega bobagem.",
    "A cara rajada da jararaca.",
    "Amar dá drama.",
    "A sacada da casa.",
    "Após a sopa.",
    "Luz azul.",
    "Ame o poema.",
    "A dama admirou o rim da amada.",
    "A diva em Argel alegra-me a vida.",
    "O caso da droga da gorda do saco.",
    "Zé de Lima, Rua Laura, Mil e Dez",
    "Saíram o tio e oito marias.",
    "Assim a aia ia a missa.",
    "Adias a data da saída.",
    "Acuda cadela da Leda caduca.",
    "Aí, Lima falou: “Olá, família”.",
    "A pateta ama até tapa.",
    "E até o Papa poeta é.",
    "Laço bacana para panaca boçal.",
    "A gorda ama a droga.",
    "Lava esse aval.",
    "Soluço-me sem óculos.",
    "Missa é assim.",
    "Nos ligou o Gilson!",
    "Até time demite, tá?",
    "Irene ri.",
    "Olá, galo!",
    "Ai, Bia! ",
    "Ali, lado da Lila.  ",
    "Amor a Roma.",
    "Até o poeta.",
    "Ladra pardal.",
    "Livre do poder vil. ",
    "O céu sueco.",
    "Ser belo: lebres. ",
    "Lá vou eu em meu eu oval.",
    "Eco: vejo hoje você.",
    "O muro: rever o rumo.",
    "Orava o avaro.",
    "A Daniela ama a lei? Nada!",
    "A droga do dote é todo da gorda.",
    "A lupa pula.",
    "A miss é péssima!",
    "À Rita, sátira!",
    "Acata o danado... e o danado ataca!",
    "Ajudem Edu já!",
    "A base do teto desaba.",
    "Eva, asse essa ave!",
    "Marujos só juram.",
    "O mito é ótimo.",
    "O trote torto.",
    "O treco certo.",
    "O trote torto.",
    "O voo do ovo.",
    "Ódio do doido!",
    "Oh nossas luvas avulsas, sonho... ",
    "Oi, rato otário!",
    "A rua Laura.",
    "Ato idiota.",
    "Arara rara.",
    "O teu dueto.",
    "A babá baba.",
    "Pivete vip!",
    "O Atari piratão.",
    "Roda esse corpo, processe a dor!",
    "Seco de raiva, coloco no colo caviar e doces.",
    "Amo Omã. Se Roma me tem amores, amo Omã!",
    "Me vê se a panela da moça é de aço, Madalena Paes, e vem.",
    "Luza Rocelina, a namorada do Manuel, leu na moda da Romana: anil é cor azul.",
    "O duplo pó do trote torpe de potro meu que morto pede protetor todo polpudo.",
    "O romano acata amores a damas amadas e Roma ataca o namoro.",
]
```

Comment: Boa! Aliás, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Mas acho que vale explicar como o código funciona. Muita gente pode não entender o porquê de você estar utilizando a função `normalize` ali. O `encode` para ASCII também está meio misterioso. Se quiser clarificar (o que eu recomendo), é só **[editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/486909/edit)** a resposta. :-)

Comment: https://ideone.com/Wu1EH1 <- tudo bem que eu "apelei" e usei caracteres fora do nosso alfabeto, mas enfim, não deixa de ser uma palavra, né? :-) (a palavra que usei não é palíndroma, mas a função diz que é, já que vc eliminou tudo que não é ASCII, então a string que testei acaba virando uma string vazia). Como curiosidade, deixei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494886/112052) que trata esses casos :-)

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo! Corrigi o falso positivo

Answer (score -3):

Para saber se a palavra é palíndroma ou não, utilizando função. Explicação de alguns comandos: ".lower()" -> Retorna a palavra toda com letras minúsculas. "[::-1]" -> retorna a palavra de trás para frente. " end='' " -> Faz a resposta ficar na mesma linha do anúncio da resposta, como se fosse só para continuar na mesma linha.

```
def result(palavra):
    palavra_min = palavra.lower()
    palavra_invertida = palavra_min[::-1]
    if palavra_min == palavra_invertida:
        print("A palavra é palíndroma.")
    else:
        print("A palavra não é palíndroma.")
    print()
    print('Sua palavra: ', end='')
    print(palavra)
    print('Inversão: ', end='')
    print(palavra_invertida)


word=input('Digite uma palavra: ')
print(result(word))

                                                                   #Pedreiro
```

Comment: Não me leve a mal, mas ao meu ver sua resposta acrescentou em nada em relação às respostas anteriores. Mesma lógica, mesmas funções. Aliás, se quiser imprimir strings na mesma linha, você pode passá-las como parâmetro da função `print` ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/2GFUKi)), não precisa utilizar o `end` e chamar a função novamente.

Comment: Agradeço a crítica, mas a ideia foi somente mostrar uma alternativa a mais. Agradeço pela dica.

Answer (score -4):

Para decide ser a palavra é ou não é palíndroma

```
f=input('Digite uma frase:  ')
if f==f[::-1]:
    print('A frase é palíndromo --> %s'%(f))
else:
    print('A frase não é palíndromo --> %s'%(f))
```

Comment: Olá colega. Não leve a mal o comentário, mas essa resposta não parece complementar em nada a resposta existente, que foi dada em 2016 e tem exatamente a mesma solução.

Comment: Acho que ele pegou daqui https://caveiratech.com/forum/programacao-desenvolvimento-bancos-de-dados/saber-se-a-palavra-e-palindrome-python/

Answer (score -4):

```
frase = str.upper(input('Digite uma frase: ')).strip()
fraseLimpa = str.replace(frase, ' ','')
print('A frase "{}" eh um polindromo?'.format(frase))
if fraseLimpa == fraseLimpa[::-1]:
    print('Sim')
else:
    print('Nao')
```