# Como fazer com CSS um parágrafo com letra Capitular (Drop Caps)

Tags: css, html5, css3, ux, ui

Eu gostaria de estilizar apenas a primeira letra de cada parágrafo do meu texto, mas não quero ter que separar essa letra com um `<span>`, pois quero manter a semântica correta da palavra, e não ter que "quebrá-la" com uma tag.

Por exemplo o que eu **não quero** é isso:

```css
span {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p><span>L</span>orem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, excepturi.</p>
  <p><span>I</span>psum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
```

Existe alguma forma de estilizar com CSS apenas a primeira letra para algo semelhante a essa imagem, mas sem precisar separá-la em outra tag?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basta usar o pseudo-elemento [`first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter), que como o próprio nome diz, corresponde à primeira letra do elemento em questão:

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, excepturi.</p>
  <p>Ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
```

Alguns detalhes a se atentar, pois a definição de "primeira letra" nem sempre é trivial. Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter):

- Caracteres de pontuação (que são aqueles definidos pelas [categorias Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm): [Ps (open)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ps/list.htm), [Pe (close)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pe/list.htm), [Pi (initial quote)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pi/list.htm), [Pf (final quote)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pf/list.htm) e [Po (others)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm)) que estejam imediatamente antes da primeira letra também são alterados por `first-letter`.

  Veja no exemplo abaixo que tanto as aspas de abertura quanto a letra `I` têm seu estilo alterado:

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p>"Ipsum dolor sit amet."</p>
</section>
```

- Alguns idiomas possuem caracteres cuja versão maiúscula é representada como duas letras. Um exemplo é o [caractere alemão `ß`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm), que quando [transformado em maiúsculo vira `SS`](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/25/473632.html). Neste caso, as duas letras `S` terão seu estilo alterado.

  No exemplo abaixo eu uso [`text-transform: uppercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) para transformar o `ß` em maiúscula, veja que o resultado tem `SS` em vermelho.

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p>ßabc</p>
</section>
```

- Por  fim, o pseudo-elemento [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pode colocar algum texto no início do elemento. Neste caso, esse texto também será afetado por `first-letter`.

  No exemplo abaixo eu coloco um texto antes do parágrafo usando `before`. Veja que neste caso `first-letter` considerou a primeira letra do conteúdo adicionado, em vez do texto do parágrafo:

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

p::before{
  content: "Adicionando texto antes de " attr(type);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p>abc</p>
</section>
```

---

Para ter um efeito mais próximo à imagem da pergunta, veja a [resposta do @fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340166/112052).

Comment: Ótimos exemplos e casos de usso, realmente existem algumas "peculiaridade" que devemos ter em mente!

Comment: +1 Excelente resposta, demonstra alguns _edge cases_ com bastante exemplo e link para documentações. Show de bola!

Answer (score 5):

Nada a acrescentar relativo às outras respostas, fora o uso do `float: left` para ter um efeito mais parecido com o print da pergunta.

```css
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc luctus rhoncus enim, eget sodales tellus accumsan a. Vestibulum eu tellus pretium, varius mauris ut, ullamcorper mi. Aliquam volutpat lacus a urna interdum vulputate. Aliquam dictum in justo vitae blandit. Mauris iaculis pretium massa non auctor. Ut pretium ut velit at vulputate. Sed eget pellentesque libero. Nunc cursus est erat, id suscipit risus dapibus ut. Ut vel mattis purus. In dapibus felis vel ullamcorper sagittis. Mauris malesuada laoreet nibh, eu maximus magna volutpat sit amet. Nam vehicula congue fermentum.

  <p>Suspendisse vehicula ligula eget ipsum blandit ornare. Etiam enim erat, sollicitudin eu eros sit amet, blandit fermentum diam. Vestibulum eleifend gravida leo non feugiat. Vivamus quis arcu sed ligula pharetra commodo non sit amet massa. Pellentesque congue sollicitudin hendrerit. Nullam sed efficitur nisl. Suspendisse et augue est.

  <p>Ut vestibulum magna non consectetur molestie. Donec ornare accumsan metus, vitae rutrum augue gravida quis. Donec et neque ut lacus tristique facilisis vitae nec est. Etiam sagittis facilisis nisi, vel vestibulum nunc ultricies ac. Fusce sit amet egestas nibh. Morbi accumsan purus sem, bibendum posuere tortor aliquet in. Maecenas vel ultrices libero, eu varius nisi. Pellentesque eget justo quam. Vestibulum lacinia eros eget pretium rutrum. Proin non nisl id risus mollis eleifend. Maecenas molestie erat dignissim accumsan sodales. Pellentesque non lorem in nunc auctor hendrerit porttitor non lorem. Integer faucibus ac diam eget elementum. Quisque pharetra accumsan egestas. Vivamus sit amet ipsum bibendum, vestibulum diam sed, tincidunt orci. 
</section>
```

Comment: Cara muito bom, é um detalhe que faz toda a diferença!

Comment: "Teoricamente" o `float` foi criado para simular este efeito que era utilizado em jornais. Teoricamente porque não tenho fontes, apenas ouvi uma vez isso e faz sentido pra mim. hahahaha

Comment: Na verdade o float é para isso mesmo, mas "teoricamente" usam para fazer grid e colunas rss

Comment: Fiz um teste com `margin: -5px 5px -15px 0px` e ficou bem mais parecido com solicitado

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar `p::first-letter`

Selecione e estilize a primeira letra de cada elemento `<p>`

**Definição e Uso**

O seletor `::first-letter` é usado para adicionar um estilo à primeira letra do seletor especificado.

**Nota**: As seguintes propriedades podem ser usadas com `::first-letter`:

- propriedades da fonte
- propriedades de cor
- propriedades de fundo
- propriedades da margem
- propriedades de preenchimento
- propriedades de fronteira
- decoração de texto
- vertical-align (somente se float for 'none')
- text-transform
- line-height
- float
- clear

> **Nota**: O seletor `::first-letter` só pode ser usado com elementos de nível de bloco.

Fonte [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp)

**Exemplo**

```css
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, excepturi.</p>
  <p>Ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Valeu Netinho obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Cara, você copiou e colou a tradução do W3Schools na resposta?

Answer (score 3):

Sim, basta usar o seletor `::first-letter` e aplicar o estilo que deseja.

```css
section p {
  vertical-align:text-top;
}

section p::first-letter{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -.4rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Obrigado Leozera!

Answer (score 3):

Hugo,

Acho que é isso que você procura.

```css
p {
 font-size: 12px;
}
p:first-letter {
 font-size:300%;
}
```

```html
<p>Este texto destina-se a demonstrar o 
 pseudo-elemento first-letter, bla...bla...bla...
bla... bla...bla...bla...bla...bla... bla...bla...
bla... bla...bla...bla...bla...bla... bla...bla...</p>
```

Font: https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/pseetut.php

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Renan